# Understanding a Lagrangian partial derivative derivation involving a coordinate change

Tags: partial-derivative, euler-lagrange-equation

In the context of a coordinate change from $q \rightarrow q'$ and $\dot{q} \rightarrow \dot{q'}$

> [image]

> [image]

On pg. 139 of *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics* the author asserts:

> [image]

**Question:** What justifies the very last step, namely that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}'} \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial q'} \dot{q}' + \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} \right) = \frac{\partial q}{\partial q'}
$$

?